# find the number of fixed points in the $A$

Tags: proof-verification, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

**[NBHM_PhD Screening Test_2005, Topology]**

> Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that
>   $|f(x)-f(y)|\le\frac{1}{2}|x-y|$ $\forall x,y \in [0,1]$. Let
>
> $A=${$x\in
> [0,1]:f(x)=x$}. How many number of elemets are there in $A$?

If $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ is uniformly continuous. Choosing $\delta(\epsilon)=2\epsilon$.Then, it must be having atleast one fixed point  by Fixed-point Theorem. Can you please help me, where did I go wrong?

Comment: I’m wondering too... Isn’t it $1$ by the Contraction Mapping Theorem?

Comment: And the second thing I’m wondering is why does this question appear in a PhD screening test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c$ is the fixed point, then setting $x=y=c$ in the given relation gives $0\lt 0$ which is clearly a contradiction. Hence, no fixed points exist.

---

If the inequality is not strict, i.e., $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\frac 12|x-y|$, then, by definition, $f$ is a contraction mapping on $[0,1]$ and by the [Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), there is exactly $1$ fixed point $c$ of $f$ (which can be computed using [fixed point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) starting with an arbitrary seed).

Comment: Sorry brother! It was a type error.

Comment: @N.Maneesh, answer revised to reflect the edits in the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is $|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{1}{2}|x-y|$ and not $|f(x)-f(y)| \le\frac{1}{2}|x-y|$ !!

If $x_0$ is a fixed point, let $x=y=x_0$. Then you get $0<0$, which is absurd !

Comment: sorry! i am apologizing for type error.

Comment: If you really have $|f(x)-f(y)|\le\frac{1}{2}|x-y|$, then $f$ has exactly one fixed point, by Banach's theorem.